# Get Regex Result as group Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find expression but I want the value as a whole, not seperate values:

```
test = "code.coding = 'DS-2002433E172062D';"
find = re.compile('[A-Z,\d]')
hey= re.findall(find,str(test))
print hey
response = ['D, 'S', '2', '0', '0', '2', '6', '6', '8', '0', '3', 'E', '1', '7', '2', '0', '6', '2', 'D']
```

However I want it as DS-2002433E172062D

Answer (score 3):

Your current regex, `[A-Z,\d]` matches a single character in the range A-Z, or a digit.  You want to capture your entire desired string in your match.  Try out:

[`[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/OnZpaO/2)

```
import re
regx = r'[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
print(re.findall(regx, "code.coding = 'DS-2002433E172062D';"))
```

Output:

```
['DS-2002433E172062D']
```

Explanation:

```
[                          // start of single character match
  a-zA-Z0-9                   // matches any letter or digit
]{2}                       // matches 2 times
-                          // matches the - character
[                          // start of single character match
  a-zA-Z0-9                // matches any letter or digit
]+                         // matches between 1 and unlimited times (greedy)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement on the previous answer I often use a utility function like this:

## Python Function:

```
def extractRegexPattern(theInputPattern, theInputString):
    """
    Extracts the given regex pattern.
    Param theInputPattern - the pattern to extract.
    Param theInputString - a String to extract from.
    """
    import re
    sourceStr = str(theInputString)
    prog = re.compile(theInputPattern)
    theList = prog.findall(sourceStr)
    return theList
```

## Use like so:

```
test = "code.coding = 'DS-2002433E172062D';"
groups = extractRegexPattern("([A-Z,\d]+)+", test)
print(groups)
```

## Outputs:

```
['DS', '2002433E172062D']
```

---

## Regex needs `()` to make it a group:

You had:

```
'[A-Z,\d]'
```

Which means: any letter in the range `A-Z` or "," (comma) or the pattern `\d` (digits) as a single match ... and this yielded all of the matches separately (and subtly omits the dash which would have needed `[-A-Z,\d]` to be included).

For groups of the same type of matches try:

```
'([A-Z,\d]+)+'
```

Which means: any letter in the range `A-Z` or "," (comma) or the pattern `\d` (digits) one or more times per group match and one or more groups pre input ... and this yields all of the matches as groups (and clearly omits the dash which would have needed `([A-Z,\d]+)+` to be included).

The point: use `()` (parentheses) to denote groups in regular expression.

Lastly, while testing you regex it may be helpful to use a debugger like  http://pythex.org until you get the hang of the pattern at hand.

## Edit:

Sorry, I missed the part about how you wanted it as `DS-2002433E172062D`

For that result using groups try:

```
'([-A-Z,\d]+)+'
```

Which means: a `-` (dash) or any letter in the range `A-Z` or `,` (comma) or the pattern `\d` (digits) one or more times per group match and one or more groups pre input ... and this yields all of the matches as groups. Note the `-` (dash) MUST come before any ranges in most (all?) regex, and it is best in my experience to put dashes as the very beginning of the patern to be clear.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You are very near , just change your regex pattern :

```
pattern=r'[A-Z,\d]'
```

to

```
pattern=r'[A-Z,\d-]+'
```

full code:

```
import re
test = "code.coding = 'DS-2002433E172062D';"

pattern=r'[A-Z,\d-]+'
print(re.findall(pattern,test))
```

output:

```
['DS-2002433E172062D']
```